# Android Studio Error: "Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution..."

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, android-studio

So, when I try to open my project in Android Studio, this is what pops up:
http://www.anony.ws/koBx
After clicking "OK," my project does open without any strange errors; however, I cannot access the 'Preview' tool that lets me see a preview of the layout, and when I go to the 'Design' tab on an xml layout, it just says "Loading configuration..." and never actually loads. I'm not sure if this issue is related to the error message that I am getting or not.

Comment: try reinstalling it. Android studio still has bugs in it as it as the 1st release version

Comment: Can you run it from terminal? Maybe it'll expose some errors.